# Where to ask licensing-related questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, legal, licensing

I've just asked a [licensing-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34343457/using-the-lgpl-as-an-open-source-hardware-license) and got downvoted unlike the plethora of other [licensing-related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/licensing). Where do I ask such questions?